# Drupal doesn't send any emails

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm working on a Drupal project but I noticed that Drupal doesn't send any emails.
I set up some web forms and noticed that none of these emails were properly send. I tested if I could get an email for resetting my password but also nothing.

But according to a confirmation message from Drupal, those emails were sent. No error logs show any problems but these email never get received in my or other users mail boxes or spam?

Googling this issue didn't lead to any solutions so I'm quite surprised! Never had issues with something like this before... What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 )  Download the SMTP Authentication Support module for drupal and enable the module.
Step 2) Configure your Gmail SMTP parameters correctly.

By default SMTP Authentication Support has the USE TLS encrypted protocol enabled.
If you are using GMAIL for sending emails you need to select the Use SSL protocol

For your reference : 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287

Answer (score 0):

you should try thrid party SMTP. Some of free one is like Mandrill.

https://www.drupal.org/project/mandrill

https://connect.mailchimp.com/how-to/24

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to properly configure the mail subsystem of your server to send the emails to the mail server of your organization, where they go throught to internet. This is done **not by drupal**, the server support team should do it. Usually [postfix](http://www.postfix.com/) is a good option.

An advantage of this configuration is that all mails from all web applications hosted in the server function right out of the box.